# How to get each wallet address balance

Tags: bitcoin-core

I’m currently having a hard time figuring how to get to check users wallet addresses and get the balances ie if a user wants to send out 3btc and they have like 10 addresses with different amounts inside them, how do I subtract the amount from each address to get the 3btc the user wants to send out?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the RPC and do 'listunspent', it will show you all amounts in a core wallet that are available to spend.

If you for example labelled an address, you can also use 'listaccounts' to see what is available in each one.

Answer (score -1):

You have to scan all blockchain (or utxo set) and summarize all unspent outputs for each address.